# How do I find the last executed line of code in python?

Tags: python

What is the best tool out there to find the VERY last line of code executed in a python program? Thanks!

Comment: pdb can almost certainly do this ... not sure how though offhand...

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted. I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: Asking for the _best_ tool to do something (which doesn't even really need a tool to do) is kind of subjective.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [trace](http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html) module and its options. A more detailed example is available at http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/trace/ .

Comment: `404 Page Not Found`. Would you like to update the link?

Answer (score 1):

try the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) module:

```
>>> cc=compile("""
def func():print(func1(2))

def func1(x): return x**2

func()
print ("I am last")
"""
,"filename","exec")


>>> eval (cc)
4
I am last

>>> dis.dis(cc)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object func at 0x9ccf770, file "gf", line 2>) 
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0 
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (func) 

  4           9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object func1 at 0x9cf63c8, file "gf", line 4>) 
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0 
             15 STORE_NAME               1 (func1) 

  6          18 LOAD_NAME                0 (func) 
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            0 
             24 POP_TOP              

  7          25 LOAD_NAME                2 (print) 
             28 LOAD_CONST               2 ('I am last') 
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
             34 POP_TOP              
             35 LOAD_CONST               3 (None) 
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```